# How does virtual A/B software update work?

Tags: ota-update

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/virtual_ab

is there any additional information or links related to the topic of software update in virtual A/B partition?

Asking for a virtual A/B update not A/B seamless update.
More info of this link details https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/virtual_ab

Comment: @beeshyams its for A/B  update, this is about virtual A/B https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/virtual_ab ending part of this document but very little is there